# Should my logs table be managed by entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to log exceptions to my database to ensure failures are recorded. I am using entity framework.

Should I setup an encapsulated logging service that records to a table which is not managed by entity framework or should I just make an ef class called Log?

Im thinking that a log is not really an entity that represents my application parts, but represents meta data which is why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a separate (bounded) context for your general logging. If logs happen to reference top-level entities you can define minimal entity definitions for these as well. Logging operations are heavy-write, so by keeping a separate DbContext you minimize the spin-up time.

When it comes to auditing (I.e. persisting change tracking) then I commonly use a pattern that hooks directly into the DbContext events and records information based on when entities are updated, inserted, or deleted.